# Unexpected ordering of `for` loop instructions in Java

Tags: java, for-loop

Consider the following extremely simple loop, which has been spaced out a little funny:

```
    /* 01 */  System.out.println(10);
    /* 02 */  for(
    /* 03 */        int i = 0; 
    /* 04 */        i < 100; 
    /* 05 */        i++)
    /* 06 */    System.out.println(i);
```

*Line 1 doesn't really matter.*  It is only there to create a starting point for the Eclipse debugger prior to the loop itself.

When I ran my code in the debugger, I expected to see the following runtime order of lines:

1, 3, 4, followed by a repeating series of 6, 5, 4, (6, 5, 4, 6, 5, 4, 6, 5, 4...)

Instead, what I got was

1, 3, 4, followed by the repeating series **2**, 6, 5, 4, (**2**, 6, 5, 4, **2**, 6, 5, 4...)

Clearly this is of little practical consequence - the loop runs exactly as expected.  But I planned to create a demonstration of a new concept for my class, and this extra execution step makes the (somewhat difficult) code I'm presenting that much harder to follow in the debugger.

I'd love to be able to counteract some of the confusion by explaining to them what is going on.  Why is line 2 being re-represented as a step at all?  What is taking place at that moment?

Comment: I can't replicate - I get 0 - 99 in order when I run this.

Comment: @EJoshuaS Those numbers refer to the numbers written before each instruction. The OP is telling us the order of instructions executed while debugging, he can't figure out why it starts from instruction 2 (`for(`) instead of following the order instruction 6->instruction 5->instruction 4

Comment: This seems to be an artefact of the eclipse java compiler that maps the loop condition onto lines 6 and 2. If I try the same code with NetBeans (8.2) the lines are the ones that you expect.

Comment: @BackSlash Ok, now I understand - that makes more sense.

Comment: @ThomasKläger Thanks. I still hope a fuller explanation arrives, but your additional data is reassuring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because Java bytecode has a single fused instruction for compare+jump, and one instruction is the minimum quantum that can have a line number or can be stepped through.

Eclipse ECJ, which you're using, appears to emphasize the jump, and annotates the compare+jump as part of the `for` loop itself. This causes a stop on `02` during every comparison/jump.

OpenJDK appears to emphasize the "compare" aspects, and annotates it as part of the for loop condition. This gives the result you're expecting, with no stop on `02`.

Neither is directly wrong, though I'd tend to favor your interpretation as well. Maybe you can convince Eclipse to use OpenJDK for this particular demonstration, or use a different Java debugger?

Below is the disassembled bytecode + debug info. ECJ puts the condition on the bottom:

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #16                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: bipush        10
       5: invokevirtual #22                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
       8: iconst_0
       9: istore_1
      10: goto          23
      13: getstatic     #16                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      16: iload_1
      17: invokevirtual #22                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
      20: iinc          1, 1
      23: iload_1
      24: bipush        100
      26: if_icmplt     13               // HERE
      29: return
    LineNumberTable:
      line 3: 0
      line 5: 8
      line 6: 10
      line 8: 13
      line 7: 20
      line 6: 23
      line 4: 26                         /* 02 */ in your code
      line 9: 29
```

OpenJDK gives a more straight forward translation, requiring an inverted condition, where no instructions are annotated with the `for(` line:

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: bipush        10
       5: invokevirtual #3                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
       8: iconst_0
       9: istore_1
      10: iload_1
      11: bipush        100
      13: if_icmpge     29
      16: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      19: iload_1
      20: invokevirtual #3                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
      23: iinc          1, 1
      26: goto          10
      29: return
    LineNumberTable:
      line 3: 0
      line 5: 8
      line 6: 10
      line 8: 16
      line 7: 23
      line 9: 29
```

Comment: This is a truly beautiful answer. I usually avoid extra "thank yous" but... *wow!*  And thank you!